# Problem in find P1/P2 in this circuit

Tags: current, circuit-analysis

Question is :

[image]

The answer I attempted is below:
[image]

Is this correct, or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: So, no current into 1 ohm's resistor?

Comment: Ohh okay so the current is 1amp and power in case 1 is =i^2R = 1*4=4 ,how it will be case 2

Comment: For case 2 ask yourself a question what is the voltage across 1 ohm's resistor and what is the current. And from which source this current is coming from.

Comment: @G36 i have added my answer below can you please check once if that is correct

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer by taking case 1 and case 2

[image]

Comment: Look good to me.